# Simple _putenv example not working

Tags: c, visual-studio, environment-variables

I tried using getenv and setenv under cl.exe under Visual Studio 2008.
getenv worked but setenv didn't. After some browsing I found out that _putenv is an alternative.

The following snippet didn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   _putenv("Hello=123");
}

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>putenv.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>echo %Hello%
%Hello%
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

`_putenv()` modifies the environment of the running process, not the parent process, which is what you're looking at with the `echo` command after the `putenv.exe` program finishes.

Comment: How to have it working similar to how setenv works under unix environment?

Comment: @ShrutiSingh - The envornment is inherited. `putenv` and `setenv` does the same job.

Comment: @ShrutiSingh, it works already pretty much the same as setenv

Answer (score 1):

Try starting a new shell after the `putenv`. It affects the future. When a process ends it goes back to the past envirnoment that it came from.